# Combining and editing multiple html/browser bookmark files

Tags: html-files

I have a folder containing 14 (Chrome, Opera, Explorer, UC, and Firefox) “bookmark.html” files that I’ve saved off for the last 3 years. When I bring up a number of these files in any of my browsers I notice that all the files look identically formatted: Folder Name formatting (font) is consistent and nested folders do not employ any unique text or text position (e.g., indented) formatting. One, the Firefox bookmark file, seems to include a helpful line of (indented) explanatory text directly following most website links.

I find the similarity between browser .html bookmark files encouraging.

I’m very happy to surf the web using the html file in a browser, searching it directly and employing the live website links these files present but 14 separate files is a bit much.

Is there a way to easily combine these files into one file—specifically: 
a) can they easily be combined by a (Notepad) copy paste operation? or 
b) can they easily be combined by an import (html file a; then file b; then…) operation?

THEN is there a way to take the combined file, import it into a (any) browser, and then use the Bookmark Manager to selectively: 
- rearrange (and delete) Bookmarks; and 
- rename Folders—without destroying the look or integrity of the file
then export the result and have a combined, reordered, and cleaned up file.

Comment: I'd think the easiest way to combine them is to import then each into a supported browser and then export them into a single new file. It may be possible to combine them in a text editor too, as they are webpage files (HTML) but you'd have to manually remove various tags and elements to fit each one together and the end result may not be as visually useful.

Comment: see "Answer #1"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I ended up importing each into Firefox, appending one at a time to the existing bookmark file and taking a while, using the Firefox Bookmarks/Show All Bookmarks interface to rearrange/edit those...and then go on to the next .htm file...finally exporting them to a single .html file (and keeping the active set of modified Firefox bookmarks).
The Firefox

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, but I believe this question will live for a long time.

I've just reconciled multi-year collections of bookmarks from five Windows systems ... 2 xp, 2 win.7 and a win.10 machine.  Each machine had both Chrome and Firefox running.

The bookmark editing tools in any version of Firefox are clunky, at best.  And the bookmark editing tools in Chrome Win 10 and Chrome Win 7 aren't very user friendly either.

The BEST bookmark editor I found was in Chrome Win.xp.  It's got a legible, compact display screen.  You can drag-and-drop bookmarks and add, delete and rename folders easily.

Chrome missed the boat in not keeping that bookmark display/editor.

The process starts with saving '.html copies of the Firefox/Chrome bookmarks from each CPU.  Index/store them on a jump drive.

In Chrome.xp, open the bookmark manager and structure a master bookmark template.   The 'root' directory structure should only have a few entries that fit into the bookmark bar in either Chrome or Firefox.

Append the archived '.html files one at a time.

After each upload, manually smush (technical term-of-art) the bookmarks into the structured MASTER bookmark file.  You've only got a single screen for editing, so the process isn't great.

When finished, you can re-distribute the master '.html bookmark file across Firefox/Chrome on your various CPUs.

It's still painful, but it's do-able.

As an open question ... can anyone suggest a good split-screen editor that can handle editing side-by-side '.html files?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).